# rjags error "Current value is inconsistent with data"

Tags: r, jags

When running a rather complicated model in JAGS via rjags, I get an error

```
Error: Error in node ttt3[126,509]
Current value is inconsistent with data
```

The strange thing is that I get this error after the model has initialized (including an adaptation period) and burned in for 50000 iterations.  That is, jags.model() runs fine, update() runs fine, but coda.samples() returns the above error after several days of computation (I expect the model to take about 20 days to fit, if everything worked properly).  So it seems that the MCMC algorithm is accepting a proposal for a posterior sample that JAGS then feels is inconsistent with the data, which I would have thought was impossible!

I would greatly appreciate any insight about what might be going on here.  Unfortunately, I have no reproducible example other than my full model, which takes several days to fit.  I can probably provide the full model specification and the data upon request.  I don't even know for sure if my example is reproducible, though I have encountered the same error twice in a row (but presumably the error arises stochastically during the MCMC fitting?).

I've posted a bit more about the outlines of the model at [Martyn's page here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/6b54ae8c/).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it's a bug in JAGS. I keep getting the same thing, too. It's about the beta conjugate distribution.